# PostgreSQL json extraction

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have json data about flight reservations coming from a MongoDB. This data is inseted into a PostgreSQL table and the data type is json. The itinerary information has the following structure.

```
[
  {
    "segments": {
      "1": {
        "airline": "G8",
        "flight_number": "761",
        "arrival-date": "2018-11-02T12:45:00",
        "arrival_airport": "CCU",
        "departure_date": "2018-11-02T11:35:00",
        "departure_airport": "BBI",
        "operating_airline": "G8",
        "stops": 0,
        "index": 1,
        "duration": 4200
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "segments": {
      "2": {
        "airline": "6E",
        "flight_number": "775",
        "arrival-date": "2018-11-03T00:30:00",
        "arrival_airport": "BBI",
        "departure_date": "2018-11-02T23:20:00",
        "departure_airport": "CCU",
        "operating_airline": "6E",
        "stops": 0,
        "index": 2,
        "duration": 4200
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The number of segments is unknown. How can this be split into multiple records so that each segment becomes a record?
json_array_elements is a function I am already using and if I use `json_array_elements(data->'flights')->'segments'`, I get output like this

```
{
  "1": {
    "airline": "AI",
    "flight_number": "20",
    "arrival_airport": "CCU",
    "arrival-date": "2018-10-17T16:40:00",
    "departure_date": "2018-10-17T14:25:00",
    "departure_airport": "DEL",
    "operating_airline": "AI",
    "stops": 0,
    "index": 1,
    "duration": 8100
  },
  "2": {
    "airline": "AI",
    "flight_number": "230",
    "arrival_airport": "DAC",
    "arrival-date": "2018-10-17T20:25:00",
    "departure_date": "2018-10-17T19:00:00",
    "departure_airport": "CCU",
    "operating_airline": "AI",
    "stops": 0,
    "index": 2,
    "duration": 3300
  }
}
```

How can this be converted into individual records? I would like to execute an insert like this -

```
insert into stage_itinerary (segment_id,airline,flight_number,arrival_aiport...)  select (....)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a very good use case for stacking multiple lateral queries, because each lateral query can refer to all the objects defined before it.

```
SELECT a4.*
FROM test
, LATERAL (SELECT a1->'segments' a2 FROM jsonb_array_elements(a) a1) a1
, LATERAL (SELECT value FROM jsonb_each(a2)) a3                    
, LATERAL (SELECT * 
           FROM jsonb_to_record(a3) a4 
           ("index" int, stops int, airline text, duration int, 
            "arrival-date" timestamptz, flight_number text, departure_date text,
            arrival_airport text, departure_airport text, operating_airline text)
          ) a4
```

If you are lucky enough to be using postgresql 12 or higher, then the above query can be written more elegantly as:

```
SELECT a2.*
FROM test
, LATERAL (SELECT * FROM jsonb_path_query(a, '$.*.*') a1 ) a1
, LATERAL (SELECT * 
           FROM jsonb_to_record(a1) a2 
          ("index" int, stops int, airline text, duration int, 
           "arrival-date" timestamptz, flight_number text, departure_date text,
           arrival_airport text, departure_airport text, operating_airline text)
) a2
```

Here is the setup code:

```
CREATE TABLE test (a) AS SELECT 
'[
  {
    "segments": {
      "1": {
        "airline": "G8",
        "flight_number": "761",
        "arrival-date": "2018-11-02T12:45:00",
        "arrival_airport": "CCU",
        "departure_date": "2018-11-02T11:35:00",
        "departure_airport": "BBI",
        "operating_airline": "G8",
        "stops": 0,
        "index": 1,
        "duration": 4200
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "segments": {
      "2": {
        "airline": "6E",
        "flight_number": "775",
        "arrival-date": "2018-11-03T00:30:00",
        "arrival_airport": "BBI",
        "departure_date": "2018-11-02T23:20:00",
        "departure_airport": "CCU",
        "operating_airline": "6E",
        "stops": 0,
        "index": 2,
        "duration": 4200
      }
    }
  }
]'::jsonb
```

Answer (score 2):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8272d7830369d4ff98c28e5d04dfd963)

You can use `json_array_elements()`:

```
SELECT
    elems
FROM 
    mytable,
    json_array_elements(my_segments_column) elems
```

---

If you want to update your table with the split data, you need to insert the new data and remove the old one. This can be done in one query using a CTE (`WITH` clause):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dc6422c1cc1be3febe81d43e40b04588)

```
WITH del AS (
    DELETE FROM mytable
    RETURNING my_segments_column
)
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT
    elems
FROM 
    del,
    json_array_elements(my_segments_column) elems;
```

Within the CTE, all data is removed, but returned through the `RETURNING` clause. This returned data is used do calculate the split records as shown above, which will be inserted afterwards.

Comment: Apologies for not making the problem clear. I have edited my question.